# why pool.map in python doesn't work

Tags: windows, multiprocessing, python-3.5

```
import multiprocessing as mul

def f(x):
    return x**2

pool = mul.Pool(5)
rel  = pool.map(f,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

print(rel)
```

When I run the program above, the application is stuck in a loop and can't stop.
I am using python 3.5 in windows, is there something wrong?

This is what I see on my screen:

[image]

I am new to finance data analysis; and I am trying to find out a way to solve the big data problem with parallel computing.

Comment: Break it and try again. As written (and as I've just tested), this code should work flawlessly. It's probably not your code, it's the system you're using. What platform are you on?

Answer (score 6):

Its not working because you are typing the commands in a shell; try saving the code in a file and running it directly.

Don't forget to copy the code correctly, you were missing a very important `if` statement (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction)).

Save this to a file, for example `example.py` on the desktop:

```
import multiprocessing as mul

def f(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mul.Pool(5)
    rel  = pool.map(f,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

    print(rel)
```

Then, open a command prompt and type:

```
python %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\example.py
```

Comment: This works for me. Any idea why it would not work in Jupyter notebook or when typing in commands in a shell?

Comment: I found one way to use pool.map in Jupyter notebook and with commands in a shell from the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313732/jupyter-notebook-never-finishes-processing-using-multiprocessing-python-3 . It involves saving the function in a separate .py file and then importing it.