# Python multiprocessing windows and jupyter

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

I am trying to run some multiprocessing routine using [pathos](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathos) package. Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def square(x):
    return x*x

if __name__=="__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    p = mp.Pool(3)
    function_results = p.map(square,[1,2,3]) #ordered
    p.close()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I am trying it to run it on Win 10 and using Jupyter notebook.

The code does not run and generates the following error:

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 252, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 337, in get
    return ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'square' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

This code ran fine on Ubuntu 16.04. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: @georgexsh  python 3.5

Comment: works for me with python3.5 in windows 7

Comment: @georgexsh, can you try it through Jupyter? I tried on Win 7 and got the same error

Comment: nope, but I suggest you do not use multiprocessing with jupyter notebook, behind the scene, jupyter have complex internal logic, which would not play well with mp very likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try put the function `square` in a separate file then import it, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47374811/5773513)