# Why Can't Jupyter Notebooks Handle Multiprocessing on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

On my windows 10 machine (and seemingly other people's as well), Jupyter Notebook can't seem to handle some basic `multiprocessing` functions like `pool.map()`.  I can't seem to figure out why this might be, even though a solution has been suggested to call the function to be mapped as a script from another file. My question, though is **why** does this not work? Is there a better way to do this kind of thing beyond saving in another file?

Note that the solution was suggested in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313732/jupyter-notebook-never-finishes-processing-using-multiprocessing-python-3). But I'm left wondering why this bug occurs, and whether there is another easier fix. To show what goes wrong, I'm including below a very simple version that hangs on my computer where the same function runs with no problems when the built-in function `map` is used.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

# create a grid 
iterable = [3, 5, 10]

def add_3(iterable):
    a = iterable + 3
    return a

# Below runs no problem
results = list(map(add_3, iterable))
print(results)

# multiprocessing attempt (hangs)
def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    results = pool.map(add_3, iterable)    
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":  #Required not to spawn deviant children    
    results = main()
```

Edit: I've just tried this in Spyder and I've managed to get it to work.  Unsurprisingly running the following didn't work.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":  #Required not to spawn deviant children    
    results = main()
print(results)
```

But running it as the following does work because map uses the yield command and isn't evaluated until called which gives the typical problem.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":  #Required not to spawn deviant children    
    results = main()
    print(results)
```

edit edit:

From what I've read on the issue, it turns out that the issue is largely because of the ipython shell that jupyter uses.  I think there might be an issue setting **name**.  Either way using spyder or a different ide solved the problem, as long as you're not still running the multiprocessing function in an iPython shell.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem like this. I can't use multiprocessing with function on the same script. The solution that works is to put the function on different notebook file and import it use ipynb:

```
from ipynb.fs.full.script_name import function_name

pool = Pool()
result = pool.map(function_name,iterable_argument)
```