# Why this multiprocessing code hangs in perpetuity?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

Trying to parallelize some code in Python. Both methods, apply and map from the multiprocessing library, hang in perpetuity when executing the following code.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

#the following function will be parallelized. 
def howmany_within_range(row, minimum, maximum):
    """Returns how many numbers lie within `maximum` and `minimum` in a given `row`"""
    count = 0
    for n in row:
        if minimum <= n <= maximum:
            count = count + 1
    return count

# Step 1: Create data 
np.random.RandomState(100)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[200000, 5])
data = arr.tolist()
data[:5]

# Step 2: Init multiprocessing.Pool()
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

# Step 3: `pool.apply` the `howmany_within_range()`
results = [pool.apply(howmany_within_range, args=(row, 4, 8)) for row in data]

# Step 4: close
pool.close()    

print(results[:10])
```

The other method pool.map also hangs:

```
# Redefine, with only 1 mandatory argument.
def howmany_within_range_rowonly(row, minimum=4, maximum=8):
    count = 0
    for n in row:
        if minimum <= n <= maximum:
            count = count + 1
    return count

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

results = pool.map(howmany_within_range_rowonly, [row for row in data])

pool.close()

print(results[:10])
```

What is wrong?

Ps. Working on Python 3.8.11 (Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4)

Comment: Both work fine for me. But your first version isn't multiprocessing: You need to use `.apply_async` for that (and don't forget to collect the results via `.get()` on the list elements). Anyways, I recommend to use the second version, maybe switch to `.starmap` to use more function arguments.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313732/jupyter-notebook-never-finishes-processing-using-multiprocessing-python-3): This seems similiar to your problem? The issue seems to be the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: So it runs fine natively in python with ```if __name__="__main__":``` to stop ```mp.Pool()``` throwing an error. However ```size=[200000, 5]``` is huge. When I cut this to 200 it ran fine.

Comment: Multiprocessing is difficult to get working with IPython (Jupyter) on Windows. This is because the newly spawned child process must `import` the main file to have access to the functions and values not explicitly passed as arguments to the target function. the "interactive" part of **I**Python means there's no "main" file to be imported always